# Git: definition of upward/downward directions between branches feels counterintuitive

Tags: git, merge

I am reading the *gitworkflows* documentation at https://git-scm.com/docs/gitworkflows (can be also read in "man gitworkflows"), but the definition of the upward/downward directions between branches feels counterintuitive to me.  I failed to make sense of it, so I am wondering if there is anything that I am missing.

Specifically, the "Managing Branches > Graduation" section of the above linked documentation says

> **Graduation**
>
> As a given feature goes from experimental to stable, it
> also "graduates" between the corresponding branches of the software.
> *git.git* uses the following integration branches:
>
> - *maint* tracks the commits that should go into the next "maintenance
>   release", i.e., update of the last released stable version;
> - *master* tracks the commits that should go into the next release;
> - *next* is intended as a testing branch for topics being tested for
>   stability for master.
>
> There is a fourth official branch that is used slightly differently:
>
> - *seen* is an integration branch for things that are not
>   quite ready for inclusion yet (see "Integration Branches" below).
>
> UPDATE: `seen` was originally named `pu` (proposed updates) at time of posting.
>
> Each of the four branches is usually a direct descendant of the one
> above it.

The last sentence seems to imply that *maint* > *master* > *next* > *seen* is the downward direction (because *master* is the descendent of *maint*, etc).

However, the documentation goes on to say

> Conceptually, the feature enters at an unstable branch (usually *next*
> or *pu*), and "graduates" to *master* for the next release once it is
> considered stable enough.
>
> **Merging upwards**
>
> The "downwards graduation" discussed above [...]

So, in the last sentence, the documentation actually defines the propagation of new features in the direction of *next* > *master* as "downward graduation".  This is the opposite to my earlier impression that *master* > *next* is the downward direction.

To me, defining *maint* > *master* > *next* > *seen* as the downward direction feels not only more natural, but also more consistent with the definition of upstream/downstream repositories.  We usually clone a remote "upstream" repository to a local repository, implement new features, and push them "upwards" to the remote repository.  (Note that the last step here is called "pushing upwards".) This overall procedure is parallel to branching *next* from *master*, implement new features in *next*, and merging them to *master*.  Therefore, I think the propagation of new features from *next* to *master* should be called "upwards graduation" as well (in parallel to "pushing upwards" from the local to remote repository).  Yet, it is called "downwards graduation" in the documentation.

Why does Git use this counterintuitive definition of the upward/downward directions between branches?  How can I make sense of it?  Or, is there anything critical that I am missing to understand this definition?

Comment: This "definition" isn't part of Git. gitworkflows is just a manpage describing how *some people* (i.e. the Git project itself in this case) use Git. You can define your own workflow and call up/down however you choose. (I agree the document is confusingly worded, though.)

Comment: Well, gitworkflows is a part of the Git manual distributed with Git (try "man gitworkflows"), so I think the upward/downward directions defined there are the official terminology of Git.  I've updated the main text accordingly.

Comment: agree that typical workflows are poorly documented. I made up my own one , other developers would probably be horrified

Answer (score 4):

Since 2009, all those downwards/upwards merges are automated by the [`Reintegrate`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/todo/Reintegrate) script used by Junio C. Hamano (explained in [commit cc1b258](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cc1b258e2aaba8cbb34aa7dca72a3a4a5a07014f)) to manage the git branches from [`gitster/git`](https://github.com/gitster/git) (which has *a lot* of branches)

But back in 2007, the [first revision of `Documentation/howto/maintain-git.txt`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/31e7bded608416e3116f9c691a4d4314f10640b6) was more explicit (and manual)

> I think the propagation of new features from `next` to `master` should be called the "upward graduation"

I agree, the [original file showed](https://github.com/git/git/blob/31e7bded608416e3116f9c691a4d4314f10640b6/Documentation/howto/maintain-git.txt#L128-L132):

> Merge downwards (`master->next`) if needed:
>
> ```
> $ git checkout next
> $ git merge master
> $ make test
> ```

By that case, if you merge `next` to `master` (in order to graduate `next` to the new git release in `master`), you do merge upward.

There was an [interesting discussion around the more modern form](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/RFC-PATCH-Documentation-new-upstream-rebase-recovery-section-in-git-rebase-tp834787p1108324.html) of [`Documentation/gitworkflows.txt` introduced in 2008](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f948dd899210e5a51cd716245affb7c121bf8791) by [Thomas Rast (`trast`)](https://github.com/trast)

Junio C. Hamano mentioned there:

> This description misses the most important reason why merging into topic branches is not a good idea. Once you merge a general purpose integration branch such as `master` into a topic branch, the branch ceases to be about the single topic.
> It becomes: "the topic and other unrelated changes mixed together".
>
> Always merging upward is a good rule, and this is when used with topic branches, there is one twist you did not mention but is worth knowing about.
> A topic that is meant to eventually merge into an older integration branch (e.g. `maint`) does not necessarily have to be merged to its final destination branch first.
> I often do this:
>
> ```
>    git checkout tr/maint-fix-bla maint
>    git am -s fix-mail-from-thomas.txt
>    git checkout next
>    git merge tr/maint-fix-bla
>    ... cook further, perhaps adding more commits to
>    ... tr/maint-fix-bla topic and merging the result to next;
>    ... and then when the topic appears to be stable do:
>    git checkout master
>    git merge tr/maint-fix-bla
>    
>    vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
>    ... and later
>    git checkout maint
>    git merge tr/maint-fix-bla
>    git branch -d tr/maint-fix-bla
> ```
>
> This keeps older integration branches stale, until the topic really gets proven to be regression-free in the field.
> This workflow is safer and more suitable for a final integration branch, to which a known breakage is better than an unintended regression.
>
> An alternative would be what the reader would assume from your description of merging upwards, which would look like this:
>
> ```
>    git checkout tr/maint-fix-bla maint
>    git am -s fix-mail-from-thomas.txt
>    git checkout maint
>    git merge tr/maint-fix-bla
>    git checkout master
>    git merge maint
>    git checkout next
>    git merge master
> ```
>
> This can regress `maint` unintentionally and then the regression is propagated upwards to contaminate all integration branches.

With:

> we use the word "integration branches" to mean the stable branches such as `maint`/`master`/`next`.

---

Note that, with Git 2.28 (Q3 2020), the documentation and some tests have been adjusted for the recent renaming of "`pu`" branch to "`seen`".

See [commit 6dca5db](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6dca5dbf93ab8cfb82e626766d5e0e60a3da555d), [commit 77dc604](https://github.com/git/git/commit/77dc6049c3ba7511c398428824a53bcb201cc005), [commit 828197d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/828197de8f2c1103e23a37d0ee32b76e899cf267) (25 Jun 2020) by [Johannes Schindelin (`dscho`)](https://github.com/dscho).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 8a78e4d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8a78e4d61588fe8e46dd7d27cb2d521b07f4a191), 06 Jul 2020)</sup>

> ### [`docs`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/828197de8f2c1103e23a37d0ee32b76e899cf267): adjust for the recent rename of `pu` to `seen`
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Johannes Schindelin</sup>

> As of "[What's cooking in `git.git` (Jun 2020, #04; Mon, 22)](https://public-inbox.org/git/xmqqimfid2l1.fsf@gitster.c.googlers.com/)", there is no longer any `pu` branch, but a `seen` branch.
>
> While we technically do not even need to update the manual pages, it makes sense to update them because they clearly talk about branches in [git.git](https://github.com/git/git).
>
> Please note that in two instances, this patch not only updates the branch name, but also the description "(proposed updates)".
>
> Where appropriate, quotes have been added for readability.

And:

> ### [`tests`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6dca5dbf93ab8cfb82e626766d5e0e60a3da555d): reference `seen` wherever `pu` was referenced
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Johannes Schindelin</sup>

> As our test suite partially reflects how we work in the Git project, it is natural that the branch name `pu` was used in a couple places.
>
> Since that branch was renamed to `seen`, let's use the new name consistently.

From the mailing list:

> The 'pu' (proposed updates) branch has been renamed to 'seen' to use a more meaningful name (after all, the purpose of it is not to contain all proposals, but to merely serve as a place to park what the maintainer happened to have seen) and more importantly, to make room for topics from those contributors whose two-letter name abbreviation needs to be '`pu`' under '`pu/$topicName`'.
>
> You can find the changes described [here in the integration branches of the repositories](https://git-blame.blogspot.com/p/git-public-repositories.html).

---

Git 2.42 (Q3 2023) clarifies how to choose the starting point for a new topic in developer guidance document, illustrating the "upward" concept.

See [commit 0a02ca2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0a02ca2383455e40cfc0b1c0818479c2d36fe6cd), [commit 5c98149](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5c98149ce4d5f57f5376fc38e512dade77a96f8b), [commit b5dbfe2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b5dbfe28a4eafc2c6c7f495983f141abcafafdfb), [commit 3423e37](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3423e372e4021b6608d4b5e65da9231425d0c455), [commit fc0825d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fc0825d56130ee3d7542c1711bd61cd1cf9bedb5) (14 Jul 2023) by [Linus Arver (`listx`)](https://github.com/listx).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit dd68b57](https://github.com/git/git/commit/dd68b57fc404e9117385879460a63a25f8b3c354), 04 Aug 2023)</sup>

> ### [`SubmittingPatches`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0a02ca2383455e40cfc0b1c0818479c2d36fe6cd): simplify guidance for choosing a starting point
>
> <sup>Helped-by: Jonathan Nieder</sup>
> <sup>Helped-by: Junio C Hamano</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Linus Arver</sup>

> Background: The guidance to "base your work on the oldest branch that your change is relevant to" was added in [d0c26f0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d0c26f0f56444d93a08121bb1f3691b2bbbfb958) ("`SubmittingPatches`: Add new section about what to base work on", 2010-04-19, Git v1.7.2-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c00cf45fa35d8aaa31c479ae7502286837fc4dc6)).
> That commit also added the bullet points which describe the scenarios where one would use one of the following named branches: "maint", "master", "next", and "seen" ("pu" in the original as that was the name of this branch before it was renamed, per [828197d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/828197de8f2c1103e23a37d0ee32b76e899cf267) ("`docs`: adjust for the recent rename of `pu` to `seen`", 2020-06-25, Git v2.28.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8a78e4d61588fe8e46dd7d27cb2d521b07f4a191) listed in [batch #7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4a0fcf9f760c9774be77f51e1e88a7499b53d2e2))).
> The guidance was probably taken from existing similar language introduced in the "Merge upwards" section of `gitworkflows` in [f948dd8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f948dd899210e5a51cd716245affb7c121bf8791) ("`Documentation`: add manpage about workflows", 2008-10-19, Git v1.6.1-rc1 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/310d188f7e1d1fbbeace17d5c62e422fd0b5a824)).
>
> Summary: This change simplifies the guidance by pointing users to just "maint" or "master".
> But it also gives an explanation of why that is preferred and what is meant by preferring "older" branches (which might be confusing to some because "old" here is meant in relative terms between these named branches, not in terms of the age of the branches themselves).
> We also add an example to illustrate why it would be a bad idea to use "next" as a starting point, which may not be so obvious to new contributors.

`SubmittingPatches` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/0a02ca2383455e40cfc0b1c0818479c2d36fe6cd/Documentation/SubmittingPatches#L13-L80):

> As a preliminary step, you must first choose a starting point for your
> work. Typically this means choosing a branch, although technically
> speaking it is actually a particular commit (typically the HEAD, or tip,
> of the branch).
>
> There are several important branches to be aware of. Namely, there are
> four integration branches as discussed in linkgit:gitworkflows[7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f948dd899210e5a51cd716245affb7c121bf8791):
>
> - maint
> - master
> - next
> - seen
>
> The branches lower on the list are typically descendants of the ones
> that come before it. For example, `maint` is an "older" branch than
> `master` because `master` usually has patches (commits) on top of
> `maint`.
>
> There are also "topic" branches, which contain work from other
> contributors.  Topic branches are created by the Git maintainer (in
> their fork) to organize the current set of incoming contributions on
> the mailing list, and are itemized in the regular "What's cooking in
> git.git" announcements.  To find the tip of a topic branch, run `git log --first-parent master..seen` and look for the merge commit. The second
> parent of this commit is the tip of the topic branch.
>
> There is one guiding principle for choosing the right starting point: in
> general, always base your work on the oldest integration branch that
> your change is relevant to (see "Merge upwards" in
> linkgit:gitworkflows[7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f948dd899210e5a51cd716245affb7c121bf8791)).  What this principle means is that for the
> vast majority of cases, the starting point for new work should be the
> latest HEAD commit of `maint` or `master` based on the following cases:
>
> - If you are fixing bugs in the released version, use `maint` as the
>   starting point (which may mean you have to fix things without using
>   new API features on the cutting edge that recently appeared in
>   `master` but were not available in the released version).
> - Otherwise (such as if you are adding new features) use `master`.
>
> This also means that `next` or `seen` are inappropriate starting points
> for your work, if you want your work to have a realistic chance of
> graduating to `master`.  They are simply not designed to provide a
> stable base for new work, because they are (by design) frequently
> re-integrated with incoming patches on the mailing list and force-pushed
> to replace previous versions of these branches.
>
> For example, if you are making tree-wide changes, while somebody else is
> also making their own tree-wide changes, your work may have severe
> overlap with the other person's work.  This situation may tempt you to
> use `next` as your starting point (because it would have the other
> person's work included in it), but doing so would mean you'll not only
> depend on the other person's work, but all the other random things from
> other contributors that are already integrated into `next`.  And as soon
> as `next` is updated with a new version, all of your work will need to
> be rebased anyway in order for them to be cleanly applied by the
> maintainer.
>
> Under truly exceptional circumstances where you absolutely must depend
> on a select few topic branches that are already in `next` but not in
> `master`, you may want to create your own custom base-branch by forking
> `master` and merging the required topic branches to it. You could then work on top of this base-branch.  But keep in mind that this base-branch would only be known privately to you.  So when you are ready to send your patches to the list, be sure to communicate how you created it in your cover letter.
> This critical piece of information would allow
> others to recreate your base-branch on their end in order for them to
> try out your work.

Comment: It's great to have confirmation that the usage of the upwards/downwards directions in the Git documentation is problematic.  Is there a good way to file a request for a fix?

Comment: @dashmile The best way is to first discuss the issue on the mailing list: http://www.mail-archive.com/git@vger.kernel.org/